# Stereometry problem(difficult)

Tags: geometry

Three identical spheres, each with radius $=a$ are inserted into a cylinder in such a way, that:

1. Each sphere is tangent to the lateral surface;
2. Each sphere is tangent to the other $2$ spheres;
3. $2$ spheres touch the lower base while the third one touches the upper base;
4. The height of the cylinder is $3a$.

### Question

> Find the radius of the cylinder's base.

Comment: Hint: If you join the centers of the three spheres to form a triangle and project it downward to the base. What is the relation between the circum radius of the projected image of the triangle and the radius of the cylinder's base?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The centers of the three spheres form an equilateral triangle $\Delta$ of sidelength $2a$ and height $\sqrt{3}a$. The vertices $A$ and $B$ of $\Delta$ lie at level $a$ over the base and $C$ at level $2a$. Denote the projection of $C$ onto level $a$ by $C'$ and the midpoint of $AB$ by $M$. As $\angle(CC'M)=90^\circ$ one computes $|C'M|=\sqrt{2}a$.

The $C$-centered sphere might as well have its center at $C'$. Therefore we have to compute the radius $R$ of the smallest circle containing the three disks at level $a$ with radius $a$ and centers $A$, $B$, $C'$. Below I shall prove that $$R=r+a\ ,\tag{1}$$ where $r$ is  the circumradius  of the isosceles triangle $\Delta':=(A,B,C')$.

Looking at the rectangular triangle $C'MA$ and drawing the median of its hypotenuse $C'A$ one  computes $r={3\sqrt{2}\over 4} a$. Therefore
$$R=\left(1+{3\sqrt{2}\over 4}\right)a\ .$$
*Proof of* $(1)$: Let $Q$ be the center of the circumcircle of $\Delta'$. Draw rays from $Q$ through $A$, $B$, $C'$ of length $r+a$, having endpoints $A''$, $B''$, $C''$. Any circle containing the three mentioned disks must contain the points $A''$, $B''$, $C''$. The circle of radius $r+a$ with center $Q$ is the smallest such circle, and this circle does in fact contain our three disks.

Comment: why does R=r+a? This is exactly why I couldn't solve it. I mean, I got to this point and dead end...

Comment: @Li4ick: See my edit.

Comment: Got it. Thank you, may the spirit of Euler guide you :D